# Possible to do fixed items in react native that scroll with the user?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-scrollview

Need to have a tab bar that displays some information that is always stuck on the bottom of the screen in a scroll view that will always have more height then the device. The tab bar is simply a view. The styles bellow will simply add it to the bottom of the scrollview and not the bottom of the screen.

```
  position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
```

Sorry for asking a common question but none of the answers I have found online seem to fix my exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [react-native-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/). It has a feature for tab bar.